# Distance to leave between drilled holes in plaster

Tags: drywall, drill, measuring

I've drilled 3 6mm holes in a wall, about 30cm away from each other. They were meant to be vertically aligned but the measurements were off and it's on about a 5-10 degree slant. Because of this I need to start again (or mostly start again).

I had initially thought that I could keep the top hole, and just drill 2 more underneath but I think that the relatively short distance combined with the relatively small angle mean that this hole will be too close to the existing one and it will end up as one wide hole.

Is there a recommended distance between holes in plaster (either officially or anecdotally) so that, if I do start again completely, I can keep the holes as close to their original locations as possible.

Alternatively, is there a filler I can use (bought off the shelf) to fill these holes that would make them blend in with the existing wall (which I assume is plasterboard) and I could drill wherever I needed to?

Edit (in response to comments): The holes are being drilled to put some mounts for [shelves](http://www.ikea.com/gb/en/catalog/categories/departments/bedroom/11468/) up. The fasteners are just standard wall-plugs (that expand when a screw is inserted to wedge them in place)

Comment: Knowing *why* you're drilling the holes might be important information.

Comment: And what fasteners, if any, you're putting in the holes.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I've updated my question with some more details

Comment: Few possibilities: if you can flip the shelf standards, you might get a totally different spacing. (Granted, they might only work one way up.) Next best would be to raise everything by 2 inches. (That's totally anecdotal, btw... I have no evidence that 2 inches is the right number.) If you can't change height, I'd opt for toggle bolts, with the toggle arms vertical. If you were a hack, you'd just angle both of the standards the same way and it would probably work out.

Comment: @aloysius, Good for an answer. 2" is what I use for a rule of thumb for relocating holes whether it be plaster, drywall or even concrete, that is when I have room to do so, which is not that often. Usually I go to a different type of fastener like you suggest which will be much stronger than the pieces of plastic Ikea offers with their stuff. Although their plastic fasteners are better than many others out there. If it is plaster with wood lath, orient the toggles vertical to possibly catch 2 pieces of lath instead of going between the two. Rock or wire lath not an issue, drywall not an issue.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate Thanks for the suggestions. Shelves would only go in one way, and ended up drilling holes roughly 2" apart and all's well (so far at least!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For posterity, I'm copying my comments into an answer... hopefully this can help someone in a similar spot in the future. (Though generally speaking, hitting a stud instead of using drywall/plaster anchors is infinitely preferable.)

I can imagine a few possibilities:

If you can flip the shelf standards, you might get a totally different spacing. (Granted, they might only work one way up.)

Next best would be to raise everything by 2 inches. (That's totally anecdotal, btw... I have no evidence that 2 inches is the right number, although @Jack seems to agree.)

If you can't change height, I'd opt for toggle bolts, with the toggle arms vertical.

If you were to do shelving like a hack, you'd just angle both of the standards the same way and it would probably work out.